# Setting a default value for object properties

Tags: javascript, object

Is it possible to multiple `values` for one `property` in `objects`? Here's what I mean:

```
// Note: This will give you an error if you try this. It's just an example.
var person = {
    name: "John",
    eyeColor: "blue" | "green"
};
```

How it should works:

So for `eyeColor`, the default is blue, but if it's set to green, then it should ignore the blue.

The code above is obviously not executable, but is there something similar I can do to achieve that?

Comment: I think you're asking two different questions...

Comment: @rnevius It's one question, but it was asked in such a way that it seemed like two...

Comment: Thanks @Tgsmith61591 ! I like the way you edited the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very small example of what you're trying to accomplish, and in the same style you're trying to accomplish it... If you don't pass an arg for `eyeclr`, it will default to 'blue' here.

```
function newPerson(nm, eyeclr) {
    return {
        name: nm,
        eyeColor: eyeclr || "blue"
    };
}

> newPerson('john')
Object {name: "john", eyeColor: "blue"}

> newPerson('john', 'green')
Object {name: "john", eyeColor: "green"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a bit of reflection.

I've created a rough implementation of a function which takes an object, the name of a property and a default value. It creates [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) methods for the property in question.

```
function addDefaultProperty(object, propName, defaultValue) {
  var propValue;

  Object.defineProperty(object, propName, {
    // this method is called when the property is set
    // e.g. object.propName = value
    set: function(value) {
      propValue = value;
    },
    // this method is called when the property is accessed
    // e.g. console.log(object.propName)
    get: function() {
      var hasValue = typeof propValue != 'undefined';
      return hasValue ? propValue : defaultValue;
    }
  });

  return object;
}
```

Then you can simply create your object however you want and use that method to create properties with default values.

```
var person = {
  name: "John",
};

addDefaultProperty(person, 'eyeColor', 'blue');

console.log(person.eyeColor); // "blue"

person.eyeColor = "green";
console.log(person.eyeColor); // "green"

person.eyeColor = undefined;
console.log(person.eyeColor); // "blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to multiple values for one property in objects?

Yes, something like this will do:

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    eyeColor: ["blue","green"]
};
```

That answers your first question.

NOTE: I think your logic is a bit incoherent IMHO.

For your second requirement, I think you're better off writing a setter function:

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    setEyeColor:function(color){ this.eyeColor=color;}
};

alert(person.eyeColor);

person.setEyeColor('purple');

alert(person.eyeColor);
```

Comment: That's not the question he asked. Yes, it's a literal answer to the first sentence, but then he wrote "here's what I mean" to clarify his intent. You can't cherry-pick from the question.

Comment: You still seem to be treating this as if there were two questions being asked. There's no "first" and "second" requirement, just one question about having an object with a default value for a property.

Comment: He worded it poorly: "multiple values" refers to the actual and default values.